# Show that $(\forall a:\forall b: P(a, b))\iff(\forall a, b: P(a, b))$

Tags: logic

Can you please explain why $\forall a:\forall b: P(a, b)$ (that is, for all a it holds that for all b we have P(a, b)) is equivalent to $\forall a, b: P(a, b)$ (that is, for all a and b we have P(a, b))?

Comment: Depending on your definitions, $\forall a,b$ could be a *shorthand* for $\forall a \forall b$; that would make them equal by definition.

Answer (score 1):

$\forall a\forall b:P\left(a,b\right)\tag1$

$\forall a,b:P\left(a,b\right)\tag2$

$(1)\implies(2)$

Let $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle$ be an arbitrary fixed ordered pair. $(1)$ implies that $\forall b: P(a_0,b)$ and we conclude that $P(a_0,b_0)$. This is valid for **every** ordered pair $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle$.

$(2)\implies(1)$

Let $a_0$ be arbitrary and fixed. $(2)$ implies that $\forall b: P(a_0,b)$. This is valid for **every** $a_0$.